# Recall IntStream inside its iterate filter function

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to create an infinite IntStream of prime number, and it must be fast - produce about a million primes in few seconds.So I try to create the stream generated with filter recall **IntStream** itself:

```
IntStream primeStream = IntStream.iterate(2, n -> n + 1)
                .filter(PrimeStream::isPrime);
```

with **isPrime** like this:

```
public boolean isPrime(int n, IntStream primeStream) {
        primeStream.forEach((p) -> {
            if (n % p == 0)
                return false;
            if (p > Math.sqrt(n))
                break;
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Then is that possible? Or is there other way working with Stream to finish my task?

Answer (score 5):

The entire point of an infinite `IntStream`, is that it consumes no memory, i.e. it doesn't "remember" streamed values. It just produces new `int` values.

If you need to remember values, you need to do it yourself.

I'd suggest using [`IntStream.generate(IntSupplier s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#generate-java.util.function.IntSupplier-), with an [`IntSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html) that remembers previously generated prime numbers.

```
public final class PrimeGenerator implements IntSupplier {

    private final List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int getAsInt() {
        int prime;
        final int count = this.primes.size();
        if (count == 0)
            prime = 2;
        else if (count == 1)
            prime = 3;
        else {
            prime = this.primes.get(count - 1) + 2;
            while (! isPrime(prime))
                prime += 2;
        }
        this.primes.add(prime);
        return prime;
    }

    private boolean isPrime(int n) {
        for (int p : this.primes) {
            if (n % p == 0)
                return false;
            if (p * p > n)
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Using that like this:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(IntStream.generate(new PrimeGenerator()).limit(1000000).max().getAsInt());
long stop = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Elapsed: " + (stop - start) / 1000000000d + " seconds");
```

will show the 1 millionth prime number:

```
15485863
Elapsed: 1.749469734 seconds
```